# Wrapper function for R with optional parameter

Tags: r

I have the following wrapper function:

```
plot.histogram = function(x.var, y.var, pf) {
  ggplot(aes_string(x.var, y.var), data = pf) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", color = "black", fill = "steelblue") 
}
```

The function works fine. However, sometimes I don't want to pass `y.var` and just use the default `count` on the y-axis. Thus, in that specific case, the chart shouldn't be a **bar chart** but a **histogram**. So depending on the absence of `y.var`, the function should automatically decide if it draws a bar chart or a histogram.

So, how can I make the parameter `y.var` optional and automatically have a histogram drawn if `y.var`is not given?

Comment: Reproducible example, please. And barplot != histogram, which do you want?

Comment: You're absolutely right. Edited it: The question distinguishes now between bar chart and histogram. I didn't add a reproducible example to keep it short for the reader. It was more a functional / logical issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are set on keeping the current parameters, I would set the `y.var` to have an initial value of `NA` then just pass it on. After initially setting an object `p` you can simply pass the `y.var` parameter later on:

```
plot.histogram = function(x.var, y.var = NA, pf) {
  p = ggplot(aes_string(x.var), data = pf)
  if(is.na(y.var)){
    p + geom_histogram()
  }  
  else{
    p + geom_bar(aes_string(y = y.var),stat="identity", color = "black", fill = "steelblue")
  }
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: The `==True` is not needed when using is.na().